# Unexpected voltage in Li-po charger circuit

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-polymer

I'm confused about something with this Li-po charger circuit:

[image: Circuit]

The components are:

- U2 - Li-po charger IC is [MCP73832T-2DFI/OT](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf)
- U1 - LDO is [621-AP2210N-3.3TRG1](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2210.pdf)
- Q1 - MOSFET is [DMP3099L-13](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3099L.pdf)
- D1 - Schottky diode is [RB551V-30 D](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2202131900_CBI-RB551V-30-D_C2836062.pdf)
- D2 - TVS suppressor is [PESD7V0H1BSFYL](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD7V0H1BSF.pdf)

When USB is disconnected (VBUS/VUSB not connected) and VBAT is 4.0V, I am seeing 3.57V at VUSB. I expected it to be 0V due to R1 pulling it down to GND. I've checked on multiple boards and there are no shorts/opens anywhere.

This is the layout, the relevant part is the bottom left of the board. There's nothing on the other side except for the CHG line (U2 pin 1) routing up to the MCU.

[image: Layout]

And for completeness this is a photo of the actual board, apologies for the phone camera quality.

[image: Photo]

Can anyone explain the voltage on VUSB? The MCP73832 datasheet says nothing about it, but I can't see where else it could be coming from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am seeing 3.57V at VUSB. I expected it to be 0V due to R1 pulling it
> down to GND.*

The leakage current of D1 could be a significant factor. The [data sheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2202131900_CBI-RB551V-30-D_C2836062.pdf) shows this: -

[image]

These are typical values so, at your working temperature (say 25 °C) the leakage current might be typically 10 μA. That would flow into R1 (100 kΩ) and produce 1 volt at the VUSB node. But, on a warmer day with a slightly leakier diode you might see several volts across R1.

If you lowered R1 to something like 10 kΩ would it cause your circuit problems <-- I don't think so but you might have different ideas about that.

If you left R1 at 100 kΩ it a problem <-- I don't think so.

Comment: The MCP73832 is also rated to have as much as 2 μA of additional leakage, though the typical value is 0.25 μA (with Vdd floating, as here).

Comment: I'll try replacing R1 with a 10K and see if the voltage changes

Comment: OK, interesting, with R1 = 10K the VBUS voltage is 2.9V

Comment: So:
with a VBUS of 3.57 and R1 = 100K, 3.57/100000 = 35.7 uA
with a VBUS of 2.90 and R1 = 10K, 2.9/10000 = 290 uA

Not sure what to make of that...

Comment: I think you might have to remove U2 and see what happens then. However, it might be easier to remove the suspect diode and see what happens. The supplier of the diode looks dodgy and that diode certainly is a bad performer compared to other suppliers of the same part number.

Comment: Good call - with D1 removed, VBAT = 0.0V. I replaced it with a more poncy one and VUSB = 0.76V (which makes the gate voltage of Q1 -3.22V which will have to do. Ultimately I'll be using a fancy one from ST (BAT20JFILM) which has low leakage. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean with D1 removed?

Comment: Doh! Yes, fixed

Comment: To wrap this up - with D1 fitted as BAT20JFILM the voltage on VUSB goes down to 4.5mV. With VBAT at 3.44V I get a Vgs of -3.43V which is acceptable, Q1 is dropping < 1mV between drain and source. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds good @CharlieSkilbeck